# Web Dev. html/css/js

Tags: html, css

Опасно ли использовать transform: translate(n%, n%), где n - это любое число в процентах?
Много элементов делаю с помощью это функции и ничего критично не замечаю, но может есть какие-нибудь подводные камни?

Answer (score 1):

Безопасно.

Проценты берутся от ширины и высоты самого элемента.

Подводный камень один: использование трансформаций там, где без этого можно обойтись. Ибо более прожорливый метод, чем большинство других. Например, центрирование элемента с помощью `position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` отлично сработает, но лучше задать паренту что-то типа `display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;`.

Comment: А если, например, при анимации keyframes картинки(или блоки) были одного размера (через стили). Потом понадобилось изменить размер. И всё. Анимация уже кривая, не работает так, как нужно. Не думаю, что это безопасно. Самое опасное тут - время переписывания анимации

Comment: Тут вопрос не в безопасности, а в кривых руках конфигурирующего анимацию =)
Браузер в точности сделает то, что от него попросят, тут важно уметь просить.